# How to create new project for current class library without having to create a solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-library

I have setup an class library project in visual studio so I can make a custom hyperlink [the built in one doesn't have what i need]. I want to now make a demo project to test it but I want to be able to do it without having to create a whole new project. How can I do that?

Comment: You will still have to create a new project, but it can be added to the same solution. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460187(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @VisualVincent is correct, the above link explains how you can achieve this.

Comment: Added a more detailed answer to how you can also show the solution if it isn't present in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: @hello123 Accept the answer that helped you the most. If you cannot decide, and they are both the same in correctness and quality, then you could just accept the one that was published first. That's what I would do, anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want you just need to create a new project in the same solution.

If the solution is not seen in the Solution Explorer, you can enable the option to always show it here:

1. Open the `Tools` menu.
2. Press the `Options` item.
3. Expand the `Projects and Solutions` tree node and select the `General` tree node.
4. Tick the `Always show solution` check box.

Now you can just right-click your solution in the Solution Explorer and press `Add` and `New project`.

**MSDN Reference to adding projects to a solution:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460187(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Oh, haha. I wouldn't have bothered with an answer if I saw yours first. You beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create almost any type of new project in Visual Studio, a [Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx) is created for you;

> A Solution is a structure for organizing projects in Visual Studio...

This means that multiple Projects (and Projects of different types) can exist within a single Solution. You can see the link above for steps on how to do this, or you can follow the steps listed below:

1. Open Solution Explorer from the View menu in Visual Studio [if it isn't already open];
2. Right-click the Solution in Solution Explorer. The Solution, as far as I am aware, is always the first item in the list;
3. Navigate to `Add` > `New Project...`:
   [image: Add a new project to an existing solution];
4. Follow the steps to create your desired Project;

And that's it.

Don't forget to right-click the new Project in Solution Explorer and select `Set as StartUp Project` if you want to Run or Debug it:
[image: Set project as startup project]